# How to add footnote citation in Word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

I want to use the traditional footnotes citation with superscript numbers, like the below example.

**My question**: Is there any possibility in Microsoft Word to let me choose a specific book from my references and insert the bibliographical information in the footnote? (What I want, is the bold part in the following example)

### Example text:

As Smith says, similar broad physical movements are "still the most direct way of indicating inner turmoil."1 Zygmundi confirms their continuing usefulness in contemporary productions of other sixteenth-century plays.2

### Footnote:

1. **William Shakespeare, Hamlet, in The Norton Introduction to Literature, 8th ed., ed. Alison Booth, J. Paul Hunter, Kelly J. Mays, and Jerome Beaty (New York: W.W. Norton, 2001)**, p. 996
2. **Jasmine Smith, "Renovating Hamlet for Contemporary Audiences," UTQ 76 (Summer 2007)**: p. 960

With so thanks,
Omid

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-bibliography-3403c027-96c8-40d3-a386-bfd5c413ddbb