# How to get MS Word to use footnote citations instead of inline citations?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2013, citations

I am preparing a sizable document in Microsoft Word 2013, and I want to use the MS Word functionality for references. Imagine I have a book that the bibliography, Chicago Style, looks like this:

```
Fletch, Fletch F. 1985. *Important Quotes.* Los Angeles: Fake Publisher.
```

I want to do a footnote citation automatically with MS word. It should look like this one that I entered manually:

[image]

However, when I click "Insert Footnote" then "Insert Citation", it just sticks an inline-citation in the footnote. Very ugly, and it does not conform to the Chicago Manual of Style:

[image]

### Is it possible to change the format of the "Insert Citation" function in MS Word to use Footnote citation style instead of inline citation style?

[A similar question from a few months ago gone unanswered](https://superuser.com/questions/1098910/how-to-add-footnote-citation-in-word-2013), and there are several places on the internet where the people sort of ignore that actual question and just say ["Push the Insert Citation Button!"](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-word/how-do-i-cite-in-footnotes-in-chicago-style-in/c1337694-aa60-4142-baba-9ceb33b8fb70?page=1)

What is a work around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of right now, it isn't possible with a native word function.